# How to visualize response data of a Synthetic test's in Datadog

Tags: dashboard, datadog, synthetic

Well, it seems a simple question but I couldn't get a resolution for this.

I have a **Synthetic test** in **Datadog** that runs an `HTTP GET` query to an API endpoint and the response body is in JSON format and has a few attributes.

One of the attributes that I want to visualize via a dashboard is named `credits` and has an integer value.
Ex. `credits: 112345`.

- Now I need to have a dashboard in which that `112345` value will be shown and updated after each time the test has run.

  - I don't know which `Widget` in the dashboard should I use, nor how to scrap/extract the `credits` attribute value from the Synthetic test and assign it to my dashboard.

#### FYI:

- The test and it's monitor is working fine.
- I have successfully created an API `uptime` dashboard.
- If this will help, here is the assertion (based on the mentioned attribute) that defines if the test is successful or not.
  [image]

**Thank you in advance**